# Related posts by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I want to show related posts, with the same taxonomy (artists) as the current post. In the related post I don't want the current post to appear.

I am also using a custom post type. (sculptures)

This is the code I am using below, but it is showing the current post in the related post and all post not only those with the taxonomy (artists)

Does anyone have a solution

```
<div class="related-posts">
<h3 class="widget-title">Related Posts</h3>

<ul>
 <?php
 $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sculptures', 'artist' => get_the_term_list( $post->taxonomies, 'artist' )));
 while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
 ?>

 <div class="related-thumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a></div>


<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Modify the code in above answer as needed. Uses the same principle which you are after, just also remove the random ordering

Answer (score 0):

Use `post__not_in` in your query.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sculptures', 'post__not_in' => array($currentID), 'artist' => get_the_term_list( $post->taxonomies, 'artist' )));
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj, Unfortunately did not work, still showing current post and all other post not only posts with taxonomy artist

Answer (score 0):

maybe somethink like :

```
$artists = get_the_term_list( $post->taxonomies, 'artist' );
unset($artists[$key]); // don't know the context, but get the term, and remove it from the array

$args=array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'artist',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' =>   $artists
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'sculptures',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$publishedQuery = new WP_Query($args);
while ($publishedQuery ->have_posts()) : $publishedQuery ->the_post();
...
endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

just adapt $artists to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately could not get this to work

Comment: sorry, get_the_term_list() outputs html, i hadn't checked this. you have to use get_terms with according args, and then foreach the returned array of object to build your final artists array.